# Digest authentication using HttpURLConnection

Tags: java, http, google-app-engine, digest-authentication

I am hosting my java application on GAE. I have to download some external RSS page and parse it. The problem is external site requires digest authentication. Is there any way to do digest authentication using [HttpURLConnection](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/net/HttpURLConnection.html) class. I am not able to use [HTTPClient](http://hc.apache.org/httpclient-3.x/tutorial.html) as it is not mentioned in [GAE JRE White List](http://code.google.com/intl/uk-UA/appengine/docs/java/jrewhitelist.html)

Thanks beforehand for any help

Answer (score 1):

Have a look to [this](http://svn.berlios.de/viewvc/esxx/trunk/jee/org/esxx/js/protocol/) wrapper; it allows to use Java [HttpClient](http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/index.html) on Google App Engine.

More info [here](http://esxx.blogspot.com/2009/06/using-apaches-httpclient-on-google-app.html).

Answer (score -1):

You can also use [Jersey-Client](http://jersey.java.net/nonav/documentation/latest/client-api.html), it is gae compatible and much easier than HttpClient:

```
WebResource resource = Client.create().resource("http/../uri");
resource.addFilter(new HTTPDigestAuthFilter(login, password));
ClientResponse response = resource.get(ClientResponse.class);

assertTrue(response.getStatus() == 200);
assertNotNull(response.getEntity(String.class));
```